# How dependency injection work in Angular Library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, blockly, google-blockly

I have created a library using angular, where i have included Blockly library.

When i packed my library as .tgz file and installed in another application , here iam not able to access blockly,i need to install blockly again and give reference in angular.json

In some article i have read they said to give reference in peerdependency inside library package.json like

```
{
  "name": "blockly-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.0",
    "blockly": "git+https://github.com/google/blockly.git"
  }
}
```

But its not working.

How to include my reference of blockly in library itself and consume as a single pack.